# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchdata'

Tags: nlp, chatbot, torch, torchtext

How can get the training data as text (or list of texts) from PyTorch Dataset(<torchtext.data.dataset.Dataset>) Object ?  Or more specifically from torchtext squad 1 or 2 the Q&a version

I keep getting error like torchdata not defined even thought I installed and imported it thanks in advance!

!pip install torchtext

!pip install torchdata

Import torchdata

Import torchtext